# In Android, how to prevent error loading page when the browser opens a customized scheme?

Tags: android, browser

I want to open my app from a web page in browser, so I add a button in the web page, and do java script to open a customized scheme, for example, MyAppPackage://. If my app is installed in the device, then everything looks good. My app can be opened.

However, if the app does not install, then an error page will be displayed when I clicked the button. The error page is like below:

**Webpage not available**

**The webpage at MyAppPackage:// might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new address.**

**Suggestions:...**

Is there anything in java script that I can rely on to avoid such kind of error page? The reason that I use a customized URL is that I want to open my app directly without choose from a list.